# Creating an environment able to span over multiple pages or columns

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, environments, framed

I'm trying to create an environment able to understand when it's on a single/two columns layout and to span over multiple pages or columns having different style for the two cases. I would want to obtain something like this example:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9439473/share/target.pdf

I tried `framed` and `mdframed` package but they seem not to be quite configurable for my needs and seem to have problems with 2-columns layout.
Can you advise me a quite configurable package which can do what i need (see the attachment) or if not, is there a command which i can use to understand when i reached the end of page or column?

To solve my problem I'm trying to use TikZ nodes to create the frame, and i would understand when it's time to go on the next page/column to create a new node and put there the following text, but i don't know how to create the partially dashed line on corners, and how to detect the end of page or column. Any suggestion?

Comment: Mmm, see my answer to [Test if a paragraph has a page break in it?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21521/test-if-a-paragraph-has-a-page-break-in-it/21522#21522) which is somehow similar to what you want. It could be used to create some style like the one in your example file.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to raise the lines with package `xhfill`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{mdframed,xcolor}
\newcounter{example}
\newenvironment{example}
  {\begin{mdframed}[linewidth=2,
      backgroundcolor=black!15,
      skipbelow=\baselineskip,
      skipabove=\baselineskip]
    \refstepcounter{example}
    \hrulefill~Example~\theexample~\hrulefill\par}
  {\par\noindent\hrulefill\par\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\begin{example}
\blindtext
\end{example}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]