# Detect incorrect interline spacing

Tags: line-spacing

We all know the log messages about over- and underfull boxes and the draft option to easily spot horizontal box problems.

Now say I am proofing a manuscript and want to spot interline, ie. vertical, spacing, problems, possibly caused by eg. font changes, `\raisebox` fiddling or most likely inline math with fractions, sums or integrals. I get neither log messages nor any visual help out of the box.

Is there a way to get visual clues like a black box to easily spot this if the problem is only one or two points? I suspect there is some method with `luatex` or `microtype` but I believe it to be involved and haven't found anything that is obviously helpful so far. I also played around with setting `\lineskip` and `\lineskiplimit` negative. This provides a little visual help, but I would much appreciate something more clear.

Comment: Something like this answer, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166499/how-to-find-out-where-additional-lines-fit-in/172165#172165, may give ideas.  In it, one can not only look at horizontal glue stretches, but also vertical, by looking at the white gap between blue highlighted text.

Comment: If you want to see when TeX uses `\lineskip` (lines too near), the only way is to set the parameter to a very high value. The interlineskip computations are not available for the user. I'm sure it is possible with LuaTeX.