# inline text by tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont{SimSun}

\begin{document}

% Code Block I %
MM%
\begin{tcolorbox}[blankest, nobeforeafter,bottom=0pt,boxsep=0pt, opacitytext=0.2]
  \color{red}MM
\end{tcolorbox}%
MM\\
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Code Block II %
MM%
\begin{tcolorbox}[blankest, nobeforeafter,bottom=0pt,boxsep=0pt, opacitytext=0.2]
  \color{red}地方
\end{tcolorbox}%

\end{document}
```

From the "code block I", I want to get six continuous characters "M". However, the typeset gives unwanted whitespace. I think this is because the width of tcolorbox is default of `\textwidth`. How can I get a tcolorbox which width changes with its content?

From the typeset of "code block II" which contains non-ascii characters(here is CJK,for example), we can see that there is unalignment in height between characters. How to align ascii characters with CJK characters?

PS: I know `\tcbox` may be a soluntion. But I want line-break sometimes. So tcolorbox must be choosed.

[image]

Comment: `tcbox` adjust their width to thier contents, but `tcolorbox` uses `linewidth` as their defult width, unless you use `width` option.

Comment: In any case, your code doesn't compile,`[most]` option to package `tcolorbox` is missing. And my system complains about CJK characters.

Comment: Thanks @lgnasi, do you have any idea how to break lines in tcbox?

Comment: For box alignment use `baseline` or `box align` options (page 79)

Comment: Something like this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125162/rounded-box-around-placeholder-text-that-supports-line-breaking

Comment: `parbox` or `tabulars` can be used inside `tcbox`

Comment: @lgnasi: Does that mean every time I need to try for a new value(fontsize changes, for example)? Is there a common method to keep all charactors in the same baseline?

Comment: For the problem of break-line, actually I need a way to achieve auto-break-line (when the content of text reach the page margin.

Comment: @lgnasi "In any case, your code doesn't compile,...". Thank you for your reminder. I just modified my code.

Comment: Why do you use tcolorbox at all? Wouldn't \textcolor{red}{MM} be enough?

Comment: Because tcolorbox provide with the feature of "opacity". I wonder if there are better ways to get text opcacity effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need tcolorbox (which creates *boxes* and so make line breaking difficult) only to get colored, transparent text.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgf,xcolor}

\begin{document}

MM%
\textcolor{red}{MM}%
\textcolor{red}{\pgfsetfillopacity{0.5}MM\pgfsetfillopacity{1}}
MM

\end{document}
```

opacity settings don't respect tex groups, so you must reset them explictly.

[image]