# Slack style code in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, backgrounds

How can I get text to look like [Slack inline code](https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/202288908-Formatar-mensagens#inline-code)?

An example is the pinkish redish text in the image below.
[image: inline code]

Comment: Perhaps this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125162/rounded-box-around-placeholder-text-that-supports-line-breaking

Comment: ...or [Cool Text Highlighting in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5959/5764).