# File icon (folded corner rectangle) frame around text

Tags: framed

I would like to present code listings with a "file icon box". Something like this:
[image: source code with "file icon box"]

I'm aware of [listings](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/) package allowing rectangle frames. My interest is in the specific shape of the frame. I think it is not specific to source code. If it does not exist off-the-shelf, I'm not afraid of some coding to achieve this.

Comment: I would define my own listings environment (`\lstnewenvironment`) which draws the box using TikZ around the listing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would define my own listings environment (`\lstnewenvironment`) which draws the box using TikZ around the listing:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newlength{\cornerlength}
\setlength{\cornerlength}{1cm}

\tikzset{listingborder/.style={thick}}

\makeatletter
\lstnewenvironment{mylisting}[1][]{%
    \lstset{#1}%
    \setbox0\hbox\bgroup\color@setgroup
}{%
    \color@endgroup\egroup
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (L) [text width=\linewidth] {%
        \usebox{0}%
    };
    \draw [listingborder]
           (L.north west)
        -- ([xshift=-\cornerlength]L.north east)
        -- ([yshift=-\cornerlength]L.north east)
        -- (L.south east)
        -- (L.south west)
        -- cycle;
    \draw [listingborder]
           ([yshift=-\cornerlength]L.north east)
        -| ([xshift=-\cornerlength]L.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{mylisting}[language=tex,basicstyle=\ttfamily]
\lstnewenvironment{mylisting}[1][]{%
    \lstset{#1}%
    \setbox0\hbox\bgroup\color@setgroup
}{%
    \color@endgroup\egroup
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (L) [text width=\linewidth] {%
        \usebox{0}%
    };
    \draw [listingborder]
           (L.north west)
        -- ([xshift=-\cornerlength]L.north east)
        -- ([yshift=-\cornerlength]L.north east)
        -- (L.south east)
        -- (L.south west)
        -- cycle;
    \draw [listingborder]
           ([yshift=-\cornerlength]L.north east)
        -| ([xshift=-\cornerlength]L.north east);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{mylisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

You still need to add the waved line at the bottom. Also note that usually you can wrap the node around the environment content be replacing `\node {..};` with `\node \bgroup` and `\egroup;`, however, this didn't worked for the `listings` environment. Most likely some of the verbatim trickery causes issues. (This is funny because verbatim should work inside a TikZ node)

Comment: Will this break across pages nicely?

Comment: @Seamus: No, that wasn't requested. If this is required I would use the code in my answer to your question [Test if a paragraph has a page break in it?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21521/test-if-a-paragraph-has-a-page-break-in-it/21522#21522). The different layout can easily be added.

Comment: yes that was a somewhat cheecky question. But since the normal listings frame environment does break across pages, I wonder if you could "piggy back" on that by just, say, adding a triangle to the top right corner of that, rather than drawing the box yourself...

Comment: thank you very much, it's my first time on tex.stackexchange and I'm delighted and impressed of the answer (as of response time!)