# How make sure two elements stay on the same page?

Tags: page-breaking

I am writing a very simple how-to document with several screenshots. The document flow goes something like this:

```
A few sentences explaining action 1

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{action_1_screenshot}
\end{center}

A few sentences explaining action 2

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{action_2_screenshot}
\end{center}
```

However since the screenshots are often large, I sometimes get page breaks between the paragraph and the corresponding screenshot. I want the paragraph to always be on the same page as a screenshot.

I have used \clearpage after each screenshot, but that doesn't quite get what I want. \clearpage would make sure that there is a page break after each screenshot, but I still want multiple screenshots on the same page if they fit. Ideally, I would have something like this to guarantee that two items were on the same page, though wouldn't necessarily always cause a page break:

```
\begin{samepage}

A few sentences explaining action 2

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{action_2_screenshot}
\end{center}

\end{samepage}
```

Is something like this possible? I'm not really looking for figures, because those don't tend to work well with longer descriptive paragraphs. Figures seem to be more optimized for a short sentence or sidenote.

Comment: Did you try what you have posted? Looks fine to me.

Comment: @Patrick Holy cow, I never tried `samepage`, I just thought such an environment was wishful thinking on my part. Turns out that it actually exists...

Answer (score 46):

The `minipage` environment is what you're after. That is

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

A few sentences explaining action 2

\begin{center}
\includegraphics{action_2_screenshot}
\end{center}

\end{minipage}
```

Comment: BTW, this DOES work with an \item and the subsequent paragraph.

Comment: I think, using `\noindent\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}` is more appropriate...

Comment: In my case, I needed not only `\noindent` before the `minipage` environment, but also `\vspace{\parskip}` in it before the end.  Otherwise the contents of the minipage get way too close to the following content.

Comment: For those working with two columns format, `{minipage}{\columnwidth}` would be needed.

Answer (score 9):

If you put everything together into a `{minipage}{\textwidth}` environment you ensure that everything is placed on one page. However, this doesn't allow for normal footnotes, which require more work. Also you will get ugly page breaks.

I would rather use `figure` environments for the screenshots together with `\caption` and `\label` so you can `\ref`-erence them in the text. You can place two `\includegraphics` into one `figure` with separate `\caption`s to ensure they are always placed together.

You could also define a `samepage` environment which uses two `zref` page labels in the `\begin` and `\end` code. Then after one compiler run the `\begin` code can check if both are on separate pages and cause an `\clearpage` if not. The code in my answer to [Test if a paragraph has a page break in it?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21521/test-if-a-paragraph-has-a-page-break-in-it/21522#21522) could be used for this.