# ConTeXt equivalent to LaTeX's \linebreak with full justification

Tags: context

In Latex, the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Hello World\linebreak
Hello World\linebreak
Hello World\linebreak
Hello World
\end{document}
```

leaves each line fully justified (to horrible effect).

But In ConTeXt, neither `\crlf`, nor `\\`, nor any of the documented 
[line delimiters](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Delimiter) seem to have this behaviour:

```
\starttext
Hello world \crlf
Hello world \\
Hello world | |
Hello world
\stoptext
```

I've scoured the wiki and looked through the reference manual for a solution, unsuccesfully.

Comment: Did you try `\break`? `Hello world\break` seems to do.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. Not one mention of it in a 350+ pg reference manual, nor the wiki. Goodbye, ConTeXt.

Comment: @JaredKulik: `\break` is defined in plain TeX. Like LaTeX, ConTeXt also includes many macros that are defined in plain TeX without documenting them.

Comment: BTW, why do you want to do this? See the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). There may be more canonical way to achieve the desired effect in ConTeXt.

Comment: @Aditya, Duly noted. LaTeX does offer and document its own way of doing it even if TeX can be used, ConTeXt doesn't and I was left scratching my head. Not worth arguing over.

Comment: I had a specific question and got a specific answer. There's nothing wrong with that as far as I can see. See Seperate [Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254168) for background, and new [Question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256014) for followup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @egreg noted, `\break` does the job.

Comment: Note that `\break` is essentially `\penalty-10000`, so it will also cause a page break if issued between paragraphs.

Comment: @egreg: IIUC, `\linebreak` is essentially `\penalty-1000` followed by `\hskip \lastskip` if `\lastskip > 0pt`. In the LaTeX example included in the MWE above, wont `\linebreak` also expand to `penalty -1000`?

Comment: @Aditya but this isn't about `linebreak`, it's about a `break` that does not break a page with the `startlinealignment` environment.  Of course there is `pagebreak`, but that's not the point. And one also has `\hbox to \hsize bla bla \break`, but that's not the point either. Also, I'm getting a `Lua linebreak filter failed reverting to default` ad infinitum here. Any insights about it, your majesty? :)

Answer (score 1):

To justify a single line of text you use `\maxaligned` or `\startmaxaligned`. For the same effect for the last line in a paragraph you can use the `paragraph` keyword for the `\startalignment` environment.

```
\starttext

\startlinealignment[max]
Hello world
\stoplinealignment

% \startmaxaligned
% Hello world
% \stopmaxaligned
%
% \maxaligned{Hello world}

\startalignment[paragraph]
\input ward
\stopalignment

\stoptext
```

[image: Example for justified text.]

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.