# ConTeXt: Capitalize first word of first line within \startlines

Tags: indentation, context, drop-cap

## Background

Looking to reproduce the following text layout (ignore the slight curve to the text, it's a magazine scan of a Robert Frost's *Fire and Ice*, first published in 1920):

[image: Fire and Ice, Robert Frost]

The first letter is ornate and the first word is all caps.

## Problem

Using `\definefirstline` with an alternative style that sets the first word to capital letters is proving elusive. I suspect the implementation is incomplete because changing the style to use different colours or fonts works.

## Code

Here's the styling code so far (`main.tex`):

```
\setupindenting[yes, 0.75em]

\setupinitial[
  state=start,
  n=2,
  distance=\zeropoint,
]

\definealternativestyle[PoemFirstWord][\WORD][]

\definefirstline[PoemFirstLine][
  alternative=word,
  style=PoemFirstWord,
  n=1,
]

\definestartstop[poem][
  before={\startlines \setfirstline[PoemFirstLine] \placeinitial},
  after={\stoplines},
]

\setuplines[indenting=odd]

\starttext
  \input poem.tex
\stoptext
```

Here's the `poem.tex` file:

```
\startpoem

Some say the world will end in fire,
Some say in ice.
From what I've tasted of desire
I hold with those who favor fire.
But if it had to perish twice,
I think I know enough of hate
To say that for destruction ice
Is also great,
And would suffice.

\stoppoem
```

## Output

Running the code produces:

[image: ConTeXt Output]

The word "Some" is not in all caps, even though `PoemFirstWord` is an alternative style that *should* work with the `style` option of `definefirstline`.

## Questions

- How would you create an alternative style that works with `\placeinitial` and `\startlines` within a custom start/stop macro?
- **Bonus.** How would you indent the second line to avoid overlapping the initial, ornate S? (Is there something like `definesecondline`?)
- **Bonus.** How would you prevent indenting the third line?

## Constraints

- The file `poem.tex` cannot be modified (it is autogenerated).
- Cannot use the [lettrine module](https://northstar-www.dartmouth.edu/doc/texmf-dist/doc/context/third/lettrine/lettrine-doc.pdf) because it requires changing `poem.tex`.

## Related

- [Preformatted text using ConTeXt's \startlines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256014/preformatted-text-using-contexts-startlines)

## Version

```
$ context --version
mtx-context     | current version: 2019.12.06 19:45
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the mailing list, the following lines register uppercase as a font feature, which allows styling the text presented by the `\definefirstline` macro:

```
\startluacode
  fonts.handlers.otf.addfeature {
    name    = "uppercasing",
    type    = "substitution",
    prepend = true,
    data    = characters.uccodes
  }
\stopluacode

\unexpanded\def\uppercasing{\feature[+]{uppercasing}}
```

Save the above as `uppercase.tex` that can be imported and used as follows:

```
\input uppercase

\setupinitial[n=2, distance=-2pt]

\definealternativestyle[poem:UppercaseFirst][{\tfa\bf\uppercasing}][]

\definefirstline[poem:FirstLine][%
  alternative=word,
  style=poem:UppercaseFirst,
  n=1,
]

\definestartstop[poem][
  before={\startlines \setfirstline[poem:FirstLine] \placeinitial},
  after={\stoplines},
]

\newcount\LineCount
\define\AdvanceLineCount{\global\advance\LineCount 1\relax}

\setuplines[
  before={\global\LineCount 0\relax},
  indenting=odd,
  command={%
    \AdvanceLineCount
    \ifnum\LineCount=2 \setupindenting[yes, 4em]\fi
    \ifnum\LineCount=3 \setupindenting[no]\fi
    \ifnum\LineCount=5 \setupindenting[yes, 0.75em]\fi
  },
]

\starttext
  \input poem
\stoptext
```

Including the bonus questions, this produces:

[image: Fire and Ice in ConTeXt]

For more details see:

- https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definefirstline#Changing_Case