# How to achieve the whole paragraph on the same page in quote environment?

Tags: page-breaking, quoting

How can I make the paragraphs in the `quote` environment appear on the same page?

In this example I would like the paragraph `Nula malesuada...` to start on the next page:

[image]

#### EMV:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}


\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{quote}   
        \lipsum[3]
    \end{quote}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How make sure two elements stay on the same page? (duplicate)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30734/5764)

Comment: Being able to split across pages is a "feature" of the quote environment.  You could center a minipage if you want to make it unbreakable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latex command `\samepage` will set `\interlinepenalty` and related penalties to 10000 to prevent page breaking within paragraphs (it may still break between paragraphs)

```
\documentclass[ebook,11pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
\AddToHook{env/quote/begin}{\samepage }

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{quote}  
        \lipsum[3]
    \end{quote}    
\end{document}
```

For older LaTeX releases without the hook system you could add `\samepage` to `quote` for example by

```
 \let\oldquote\quote \renewcommand\quote{\oldquote\samepage}
```

Comment: I'm having the error: *Undefined control sequence `\AddToHook`*.

Comment: ah your latex is too old, just use `\begin{quote}\samepage`  the hook is just a way of adding it there automatically @A.Cedano

Comment: So I have to add this manually `\begin{quote}\samepage` every time I start a quote environment? Would there be any way to automate it in my old version of Latex?

Comment: @A.Cedano `\let\oldquote\quote \renewcommand\quote{\oldquote\samepage}`

Comment: It's working fine. Thanks a lot. I'm working with Ubuntu 18, then I have the versión `TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2017/Debian)`

Comment: @A.Cedano tl 2017, ah 4 years back, OK.

Comment: In which version was added `\AddToHook`?

Comment: the autumn 2020 release

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- It would be a friendly gesture to add the "older" information to your answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton done:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- Thank you.  Let's hope there aren't too many complaints about excess vertical space.