# indentation scope lines broken in algpseudocode

Tags: algorithms, algpseudocode

I am trying to provide a vertical line that shows the indentation in an algorithm. I'm following [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/292815/how-can-i-create-vertical-lines-indentation-in-algorithm-pseudo-code-correctly-w), but when I add some math that is higher than the line height, the lines get broken. This is the result and I also provide the code. Can this issue be fixed?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}                              % For \eqref
\usepackage{amssymb}                             % For mathematical symbols
\usepackage{amsbsy}                                % For bold symbol greek letters

\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}


\makeatletter
% start with some helper code
% This is the vertical rule that is inserted
\newcommand*{\algrule}[1][\algorithmicindent]{\makebox[#1][l]{\hspace*{.5em}\vrule height .75\baselineskip depth .25\baselineskip}}%

\newcount\ALG@printindent@tempcnta
\def\ALG@printindent{%
    \ifnum \theALG@nested>0% is there anything to print
    \ifx\ALG@text\ALG@x@notext% is this an end group without any text?
    % do nothing
    \addvspace{-3pt}% FUDGE for cases where no text is shown, to make the rules line up
    \else
    \unskip
    % draw a rule for each indent level
    \ALG@printindent@tempcnta=1
    \loop
    \algrule[\csname ALG@ind@\the\ALG@printindent@tempcnta\endcsname]%
    \advance \ALG@printindent@tempcnta 1
    \ifnum \ALG@printindent@tempcnta<\numexpr\theALG@nested+1\relax% can't do <=, so add one to RHS and use < instead
    \repeat
    \fi
    \fi
}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% the following line injects our new indent handling code in place of the default spacing
\patchcmd{\ALG@doentity}{\noindent\hskip\ALG@tlm}{\ALG@printindent}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\makeatother
% end vertical rule patch for algorithmicx
\makeatother

% for bmatrix with alignment
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]{%
    \hskip -\arraycolsep
    \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}}
\makeatother



\begin{document}

   \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Arbitrary Algorithm}\label{IS2OSLS}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \Require A matrix $\mathbf{A}$ of size $m\times n$.
            \Ensure Something.
            \For{$i$ in $m$}
                   \State{$\mathbf{X} \gets \begin{bmatrix}[rrr]  \boldsymbol x_i  & \boldsymbol x_j & \ldots \end{bmatrix}^\intercal $} \Comment{get coordinates}

                \For{$j$ in $n$}
                    \If{$i=j$}
                        \State Select a random action
                    \Else
                        \If{$i=j^3+1$}
                            \State Stay silent 
                            \State $j \gets \begin{cases} a & b \\ c & d \end{cases} $
                        \Else 
                            \State $i \gets \mathbf{J}^\intercal$
                            \State Break
                        \EndIf
                    \EndIf
                \EndFor
            \EndFor
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your code, I give another example where you can see that the rules overlap the return statement.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}

\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}

\newcommand*{\algrule}[1][\algorithmicindent]{\hspace*{.5em}\vrule\vrule
width 0pt height .75\baselineskip depth .25\baselineskip\hspace*{\dimexpr#1-.5em}}

\makeatletter
\newcount\ALG@printindent@tempcnta
\def\ALG@printindent{%
    \ifnum \theALG@nested>0% is there anything to print
    \ifx\ALG@text\ALG@x@notext% is this an end group without any text?
    % do nothing
    \addvspace{-3pt}% FUDGE for cases where no text is shown, to make the rules line up
    \else
    \unskip
    % draw a rule for each indent level
    \ALG@printindent@tempcnta=1
    \loop
    \algrule[\csname ALG@ind@\the\ALG@printindent@tempcnta\endcsname]%
    \advance \ALG@printindent@tempcnta 1
    \ifnum \ALG@printindent@tempcnta<\numexpr\theALG@nested+1\relax% can't do <=, so add one to RHS and use < instead
    \repeat
    \fi
    \fi
}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\ALG@doentity}{\noindent\hskip\ALG@tlm}{\ALG@printindent}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\makeatother

\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\lineskip0pt}

\newcommand*\Let[2]{\State #1 $\gets$ #2}


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Test 2
    \label{alg:interact}}
  \begin{algorithmic}[0]
    \Require{$\mathcal{M} := \left\{ \mathcal{N}, \mathcal{E} \right\}$ and  $\mathcal{G}$}
    \Statex
    \Function{test}{$\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{G}$}
      \Let{$\mathcal{S}$}{$\emptyset$} 
      \For{$e_i \in \mathcal{E}$}
        \For{$g_i \in \mathcal{G}$}
          \Let{$\mathcal{I}$}{$e_i  \cap g_i$}
          \If{$\mathcal{I} \neq \emptyset $} 
            \Let{$\left\{n_k \right\}$}{$\mathcal{I}$} 
            \Let{$\phantom{\left\{n_k \right\} }\mathllap{ \mathcal{S}}$}{$\mathcal{S} \bigcup_k \left\{ n_k, s_k\right\} $}
            \Let{$\phantom{\left\{n_k \right\} }\mathllap{ \mathcal{N}}$}{$\mathcal{N} \bigcup_k \left\{n_k \right\}$}
            \Let{$\phantom{\left\{n_k \right\} }\mathllap{\mathcal{T}}$}{subdivide($e_i, \mathcal{I}$)} 
            \Let{$\phantom{\left\{n_k \right\} }\mathllap{\mathcal{E}}$}{$\mathcal{E} \cup \mathcal{T}$}  
          \EndIf
        \EndFor
      \EndFor
      \State \Return{$\mathcal{W}, \mathcal{N}, \mathcal{E}$}
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Which gives

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

The new code is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}

\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}

\newcommand*{\algrule}[1][\algorithmicindent]{\hspace*{.5em}\vrule\vrule
width 0pt height \baselineskip depth .25\baselineskip\hspace*{\dimexpr#1-.5em}}

\makeatletter
\newcount\ALG@printindent@tempcnta
\def\ALG@printindent{%
    \ifnum \theALG@nested>0% is there anything to print
    \ifx\ALG@text\ALG@x@notext% is this an end group without any text?
    % do nothing
    \else
    \unskip
    % draw a rule for each indent level
    \ALG@printindent@tempcnta=1
    \loop
    \algrule[\csname ALG@ind@\the\ALG@printindent@tempcnta\endcsname]%
    \advance \ALG@printindent@tempcnta 1
    \ifnum \ALG@printindent@tempcnta<\numexpr\theALG@nested+1\relax% can't do <=, so add one to RHS and use < instead
    \repeat
    \fi
    \fi
}%
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\ALG@doentity}{\noindent\hskip\ALG@tlm}{\ALG@printindent}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\makeatother

\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\lineskip0pt}

\newcommand*\Let[2]{\State #1 $\gets$ #2}


\algtext*{EndWhile}% Remove "end while" text
\algtext*{EndFor}% Remove "end for" text
\algtext*{EndIf}% Remove "end if" text
\algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{doWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%

% increase line spacing for algorithmicx
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\algorithmic\endcsname{\itemsep\z@}
{\itemsep=0.2ex plus2pt}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\showoutput

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Test 2
    \label{alg:interact}}
  \begin{algorithmic}[0]
    \Require{$\mathcal{M} := \left\{ \mathcal{N}, \mathcal{E} \right\}$ and  $\mathcal{G}$}
    \Statex
    \Function{test}{$\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{G}$}
      \Let{$\mathcal{S}$}{$\emptyset$} 
      \For{$e_i \in \mathcal{E}$}
        \For{$g_i \in \mathcal{G}$}
          \Let{$\mathcal{I}$}{$e_i  \cap g_i$}
          \If{$\mathcal{I} \neq \emptyset $} 
            \Let{$\left\{n_k \right\}$}{$\mathcal{I}$} 
            \Let{$\phantom{\left\{n_k \right\} }\mathllap{ \mathcal{S}}$}{$\mathcal{S} \bigcup_k \left\{ n_k, s_k\right\} $}
            \Let{$\phantom{\left\{n_k \right\} }\mathllap{ \mathcal{N}}$}{$\mathcal{N} \bigcup_k \left\{n_k \right\}$}
            \Let{$\phantom{\left\{n_k \right\} }\mathllap{\mathcal{T}}$}{subdivide($e_i, \mathcal{I}$)} 
            \Let{$\phantom{\left\{n_k \right\} }\mathllap{\mathcal{E}}$}{$\mathcal{E} \cup \mathcal{T}$}  
          \EndIf
        \EndFor
      \EndFor
      \State \Return{$\mathcal{W}, \mathcal{N}, \mathcal{E}$}
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Comment: Rules with a fixed height and depth are added, they don't adjust to the current line dimensions. I'm not sure it's possible to achieve this with such an approach.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110431/15925

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution building on the posted code.  A completely different approach using `tikz` is to be found in [Problems with vertical lines in algorithmicx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110431/15925).

To modify the current code you need to use rules that do not have a fixed height and depth.  One way to achieve that is simply to write `\vrule`.  However, you should ensure minimum sizes and need to make sure that the resulting lines do not get moved apart by the `\lineskip` mechanism.  The code below covers all of your examples.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}

\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\algruledefaultfactor}{.75}
\newcommand{\algstrut}[1][\algruledefaultfactor]{\vrule width 0pt
depth .25\baselineskip height #1\baselineskip\relax}
\newcommand*{\algrule}[1][\algorithmicindent]{\hspace*{.5em}\vrule\algstrut
\hspace*{\dimexpr#1-.5em}}

\makeatletter
\newcount\ALG@printindent@tempcnta
\def\ALG@printindent{%
    \ifnum \theALG@nested>0% is there anything to print
    \ifx\ALG@text\ALG@x@notext% is this an end group without any text?
    % do nothing
    \else
    \unskip
    % draw a rule for each indent level
    \ALG@printindent@tempcnta=1
    \loop
    \algrule[\csname ALG@ind@\the\ALG@printindent@tempcnta\endcsname]%
    \advance \ALG@printindent@tempcnta 1
    \ifnum \ALG@printindent@tempcnta<\numexpr\theALG@nested+1\relax% can't do <=, so add one to RHS and use < instead
    \repeat
    \fi
    \fi
}%

\patchcmd{\ALG@doentity}{\noindent\hskip\ALG@tlm}{\ALG@printindent}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}

\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\lineskip0pt}

\newcommand*\Let[2]{\State #1 $\gets$ #2}
\newcommand*\Stateh{\State \algstrut[1]}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Arbitrary Algorithm}\label{IS2OSLS}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require A matrix $\mathbf{A}$ of size $m\times n$.
    \Ensure Something.
    \For{$i$ in $m$}
      \State{$\mathbf{X} \gets \begin{bmatrix*}[r]  \boldsymbol x_i  & \boldsymbol x_j & \ldots \end{bmatrix*}^\intercal $} \Comment{get coordinates}
      \For{$j$ in $n$}
        \If{$i=j$}
          \State Select a random action
          \Else
          \If{$i=j^3+1$}
            \State Stay silent
            \State $j \gets \begin{cases} a & b \\ c & d \end{cases} $
            \Else
            \State $i \gets \mathbf{J}^\intercal$
            \State Break
          \EndIf
        \EndIf
        \EndFor
    \EndFor
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Test 2
    \label{alg:interact}}
  \begin{algorithmic}[0]
    \Require{$\mathcal{M} := \left\{ \mathcal{N}, \mathcal{E} \right\}$ and  $\mathcal{G}$}
    \Function{test}{$\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{G}$}
      \Let{$\mathcal{S}$}{$\emptyset$}
      \For{$e_i \in \mathcal{E}$}
        \For{$g_i \in \mathcal{G}$}
          \Let{$\mathcal{I}$}{$e_i  \cap g_i$}
          \If{$\mathcal{I} \neq \emptyset $}
            \Let{$\left\{n_k \right\}$}{$\mathcal{I}$}
            \Let{$\hphantom{\left\{n_k \right\} }\mathllap{ \mathcal{S}}$}{$\mathcal{S} \bigcup_k \left\{ n_k, s_k\right\} $}
            \Let{$\hphantom{\left\{n_k \right\} }\mathllap{ \mathcal{N}}$}{$\mathcal{N} \bigcup_k \left\{n_k \right\}$}
            \Let{$\hphantom{\left\{n_k \right\} }\mathllap{\mathcal{T}}$}{subdivide($e_i, \mathcal{I}$)}
            \Let{$\hphantom{\left\{n_k \right\} }\mathllap{\mathcal{E}}$}{$\mathcal{E} \cup \mathcal{T}$}
            \EndIf
        \EndFor
      \EndFor
      \Stateh \Return{$\mathcal{W}, \mathcal{N}, \mathcal{E}$}
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I have rewritten the `\algrule` command, unpacking it from a box, so an isolated `\vrule` can fill the height and depth of the current line.  A rule of zero width is then drawn to force that height and depth to be reasonable on standard lines.  This rule is encapsulated in a newcommand `\algstrut`.  Finally the `algorithmic` environment is patched to have `\lineskip` set to `0pt`.

If you have two consecutive high lines these may now touch, but then you can fix this by adding a zero width rule of suitable height and depth to your text in these one-off cases.  This can be done using `\algstrut[1]` or some large factor on the given line.

It also turns out to be necessary to have a taller strut on `\State` lines, so I have provided a new command `\Stateh` that includes this.

Incidentally I have removed the code for the `bmatrix` alignment, as the `mathtools` package now provides `bmatrix*` which has an alignment option.
Also I have use `\hphantom` instead of `\phantom` in your example, as you are only interested in adjust the horizontal spacing.

Comment: I tried your code and it almost work with my real algorithm. There are two issues, first the rules overlap with a return statement. I guess this could be solved by your example on adding a zero width rule? Could you provide an example on how to do this? In another algorithm I still found a couple of places where the lines are discontinuous.

Comment: I have updated the question showing the example where the rule overlap with the return statement.

Comment: Hi again, there's something else. I also had a bit of code to increase the spacing of within the algorithm. If I remove this code then your solution is perfect, but if I put it I still get the broken line in the return statement. Do you think that your answer can also consider this case? I modified my update 2 to show you this.

Comment: But on my end it doesn't work still. I get even a greater separation before the return statement. Are you sure it works on your end? What is missing?

Comment: So as I understand it, you're using `\alghigher` to compensate?

Comment: But isn't that some sort of hack?

Comment: I have now rearranged the answer covering all your examples.  You can now just use `\algstrut[1]` instead of the previous `\alghigher{....}` and I have provide `\Stateh` that incoporates this.  Yes, this is all a hack, as is the code you started with.  Ultimately one would want to rewrite and restructure the algorithmicx code, so such hacking is not needed.

Comment: I'm still having problems with the code as it is not working for some examples. Is there something I can play with in the definition of the macros that would close these gaps? they usually show up still in the return statement.

Comment: Does `\algstrut[1.5]` etc not help?

Comment: That doesn't help. It makes the text wider but I still see some gaps. Any other ideas?

Comment: Without seeing code it is hard to say.  You can post a new question.