# How to write a TeX conditional to test start of a new page (ConTeXt)

Tags: page-breaking, conditionals

Currently using:

```
\edef\lastpagenumber{\pagenumber}
```

after starting a new page, then in subsequent text:

```
\ifnum\pagenumber>\lastpagenumber
  do something
\else
  do something else
\fi
```

But sometimes `\pagenumber` does not seem to increment, even though a new page has started.

Comment: You can not test in that way (which format is this? latex and plain do not define `\pagenumber`) teX typesets complete paragraphs (including expanding all macros _before_ considering page breaks. Page numbers are not reliably known until the output routine. (search for questions about that for more info)

Comment: You need to set a label at both positions and then test if their page numbers are different. This needs two compiler runs. See my answer to [Test if a paragraph has a page break in it?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21522/2975), which might even be a duplicate.

Comment: You could also have a look at the source code of the `varioref` package which uses some code like you want.

Comment: The format is ConTeXt, which apparently defines the \pagenumber macro. Apologies if the post is a duplicate, though the referenced post is for LaTeX. Not sure how to use LaTeX packages in ConTeXt.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve with this code?

Comment: I am using an inline generated METAPOST figure as a background for text added to the text box. When sufficient content has been added to the text box that a new page starts, I want to reset the background to be empty. I am not manually editing the ConTeXt input file, but instead, generating the ConTeXt input file on the fly (using Python). So I need the code in the ConTeXt input file to detect the new page so that the background can be reset.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the perpage package.  If you create a dummy counter

```
\usepackage{perpage}
\newcounter{mydummy}
\MakePerPage{mydummy}
```

then right after every

```
\stepcounter{mydummy}
```

the macro `\theperpage` will expand to the current page number at the point in the text where the counter has been stepped.  Not necessarily right away: you might get a warning "references may have changed", requiring you to rerun LaTeX.