# Handwriting drill sheets

Tags: fonts, positioning

I am looking to create some handwriting drill sheets.  Similar to what can be found here
 http://www.handwritingworksheets.com/flash/cursive/paragraph/index.html

I also found this question:
[Writing practice sheets - dotted letters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96766/writing-practice-sheets-dotted-letters?rq=1)
But I'd like to be able to simply write a paragraph of text with a known font and have the lines placed behind, perhaps like a watermark.

I have found a git repo with some nice lines in both portrait and landscape here
https://github.com/gkthiruvathukal/kindergarten

From the kindergarten example, I would like to overlay "phantom" text (probably a dotted cursive font) over the lines that are generated.  Any thoughts?

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1cm,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\usepackage{forloop}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\newcounter{ct}
\forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 13}
{
\vskip 10pt
\rule[1.75ex]{7.5in}{1pt}
\\
\hdashrule{7.75in}{1pt}{4mm}
\\
\rule[-1.75ex]{7.5in}{1pt}
\\
}

\vskip 1cm

\end{document}
```

*Edit: I also just found this source: 
http://failuresandfixes.blogspot.com/2011/12/faking-baseline-grid-in-latex.html

So some combination of these makes sense to me, I'm just not clear on how...

*Edit: Okay, So I've gotten pretty far here.  But it seems like several parameters need to be functions of each other some how.  The line spacing, the font size, etc.  Here is where I am:

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,english]{article}

\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{blindtext} 

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1cm,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{dashrule}
\usepackage{forloop}
\makeatother

\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\baselinegrid}{%
  \raisebox{0pt}[\height][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}%
    \begin{color}{red}%
    \newcounter{ct}
    \forloop{ct}{1}{\value{ct} < 11}
    {
    %\vskip 15pt
    \rule[0.5ex]{7.5in}{1pt}
    \\
    \hdashrule[0.75ex]{7.75in}{1pt}{4mm}
    \\
    \rule[1.2ex]{7.5in}{1pt}
    \\
    }
    \end{color}
  \end{minipage}%
}}}

\begin{document}

  \baselinegrid%

\begin{spacing}{2.5}

  \usefont{T1}{wela}{m}{n}
  \fontsize{30}{15}\selectfont
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

  DURING the whole of a dull, dark, and soundless day in the autumn of the year, when the clouds hung oppressively low in the heavens, I had been passing alone, on horseback, through a singularly dreary tract of country; and at length found myself, as the shades of the evening drew on, within view of the melancholy House of Usher.

\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is another solution, without the need of calculating the line number and the possibility to span text over several pages. I used the [`lineno`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lineno) to have “every line” hook and then I redefine the line numbers to be the grid instead of the actual number.

[image: Zapfino grid]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% necessary packages
\usepackage{tikz}

% set the font
%\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Zapfino}

% increase baseline skip
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}

% define height of lowercase letters
\newcommand{\lowercaseheight}{1ex}
% define height of uppercase letters
\newcommand{\uppercaseheight}{2ex}
% define depth of descenders
\newcommand{\descenderdepth}{-0.5ex}
    % you may add more values here and then use them in the {tikzpicture}
    % to add more line to your grid


% package to have a "every line" hook
\usepackage{lineno}

\newenvironment{drillsheet}{%
    % let the "line numbers" start directly at the text
    \setlength\linenumbersep{0pt}%
    % let the "line numbers" be the grid
    \renewcommand{\thelinenumber}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
                % baseline
                \draw ((0,0) -- ++(\textwidth,0);
                % lowercase height
                \draw [ultra thin] ((0,\lowercaseheight) -- ++(\textwidth,0);
                % uppercase height
                \draw (0,\uppercaseheight) -- ++(\textwidth,0);
                % descender depth
                \draw [ultra thin] (0,\descenderdepth) -- ++(\textwidth,0);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
    % the font and color of the numbers must be set explicitly
    \renewcommand\linenumberfont{\normalfont\color{black}}
    % start "line numbering", i.e. the grid
    \begin{linenumbers}%
        % set text color to gray
        \color{black!25}%
}{
    % end "numbering", i.e. the grid
    \end{linenumbers}%
}

\newenvironment{fakedisplaymath}{%
   \begin{center}%
   $\displaystyle
}{%
   $%
   \end{center}%
}

\begin{document}
\Large
\begin{drillsheet}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed $a^2+b^2=c^2$
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
    nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
    \begin{fakedisplaymath}
       A=\int_0^2f(x)\,dx
    \end{fakedisplaymath}
    fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
    culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{drillsheet}
\end{document}
```

**Math**
Inline math works as expected:
[image: inline math]

But displaystyle math is a little harder, since `lineno` ignores display math. I added the `{fakedisplaymath}` environment to add rudimentary support for equations.
[image: display math]
But I’d say it's hard to draw the drill line for math, how about fractions for instance …?

Comment: This worked really well and is robust to changes in font.  Well done, and thank you so much.  This is a really cleaver solution.

Comment: I have the full texlive installed and it can't find your font, is there a special package just for the font used?

Comment: @MaoYiyi: The font is commercial and not part of any TeX distribution, though. But it is part of some operating systems (as Mac OS X). You can buy it from [Linotype](http://www.linotype.com/de/1175/zapfino-family.html?id=1175&name=zapfino&viewmode=family&site=&lang=de) for example. Or have a look at [fontsquirrel.com](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/) to find free alternatives …

Comment: Furthermore you must compile the example with either XeTeX or LauTeX, since the `fontspec` package requires on of these machines.

Comment: is there a way to do this with with mathmode?

Comment: @MaoYiyi: See my edit … is this what you want?

Answer (score 11):

I guess you cant make a font dotted with LaTeX you either have to use a font which is designed as dotted or stick to a font with streight lines. I suggest using a light gray instead of dotting the font. The grid can be added with [TikZ](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf), for instance.

If you use XeTeX or LuaTeX you can use [`fontspec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) and load every font installed on your system. Otherwise a list of (PDF)LaTeX compatible fonts can be found at the [LaTeX Font Catalouge](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/).

[image: drill sheet]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% necessary packages
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

% set the font
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Lilly}% from http://www.fontsquirrel.com/

% help length to store width of text
\newlength{\lengthoftext}

% increase baseline skip
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{2}

% define height of lowercase letters
\newcommand{\lowercaseheight}{1ex}
% define height of uppercase letters
\newcommand{\uppercaseheight}{1.7ex}
% define depth of descenders
\newcommand{\descenderdepth}{-0.8ex}

% set up the environment. Use the optional argument to give a line number
% if it's not calculated properly
\NewEnviron{drillpar}[1][\numberoflines]{%
    % start new paragraph and add some space
    \par\addvspace{1\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip}
    % measure the length of the text as if it's in a single line
    \settowidth{\lengthoftext}{\BODY}%
    % divide by text width to get the number of lines
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\numberoflines{int(\lengthoftext/\textwidth)+1}%
    % use a {minipage} to keep the text on the same page
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        % for debugging
%       L: \the\lengthoftext\qquad N: #1\\%
        % set an anchor for the grid
        \tikz[remember picture,overlay] \coordinate (grid anchor);%
        % print the text
        {\color{black!25}\BODY}
        % draw the baseline grid
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
            \foreach \line in {1,...,#1} {
                % baseline
                \draw [ultra thick] ($(grid anchor)+(0,{-(\line-1)*\baselineskip})$) --
                    ++(\textwidth,0);
                % lowercase height
                \draw ($(grid anchor)+(0,{-(\line-1)*\baselineskip+\lowercaseheight})$) --
                    ++(\textwidth,0);
                % uppercase height
                \draw [thick] ($(grid anchor)+(0,{-(\line-1)*\baselineskip+\uppercaseheight})$) --
                    ++(\textwidth,0);
                % descender depth
                \draw ($(grid anchor)+(0,{-(\line-1)*\baselineskip+\descenderdepth})$) --
                    ++(\textwidth,0);
            }
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{minipage}%
    % start new paragraph and add some space
    \par\vspace{1\baselineskip plus 0.5\baselineskip}
}

\begin{document}
\Large
\begin{drillpar}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
    incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis
    nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
    fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in
    culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{drillpar}
\end{document}
```

Compile this example with XeTeX twice (otherwise the grid won’t be placed correctly). To produce an empty grid use an empty environment and set the number of lines with the optional argument, e.g.

```
\begin{drillpar}[6]
\end{drillpar}
```

You may change the line width of the grid by changing the options of the `\draw` commands, see the pgfmanual for more information or ask in a comment ;-)

Comment: So I tried this with two different fonts on my system, Zapfino, and Brush Script MT, and both died horrible deaths.  If you have those fonts installed you should see something similar.  Was I supposed to change something else when I changed the font?

Comment: So I found a font that did work (Snell Roundhand), but when I added text that exceeded the page length, the document compiles with errors, and doesn't move text to the next page.

Comment: Is this somehow applicable to making it multi-page: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21236/creating-an-environment-able-to-span-over-multiple-pages-or-columns

Comment: The problem with Zapfino is that it won’t fit in the baseline and for that the `\baselineskip` and the real baseline skip in the document aren’t congruent. But you can increase by changing the factor in `\setstretch{f}`, e.g. to `4`. Furthermor you might have to change the values of `\lowercaseheight`, `\uppercaseheight`, and `\descenderdepth`.

Comment: At the moment it is impossible to let the text span multiple lines, but I’ll see what I can do …

Answer (score 6):

Here, each issuance of `\blankrow` puts a new row on the paper, while `\fillrow` allows you to specify italic (actually math) text.  The distance between top and baseline is set with length `\letterheight`, the fractional height to the midline is specified in `\midpitch` (corresponding to the font for which you wish to develop the practice sheet), while the gap between adjacent rows is set with `\parskip`.  I also assumed the height of capitals was 0.85 the height of the `\strutbox`, though that number can be changed.

If you want roman text, place the `\smash{#1}` between dollar signs as in `$\smash{#1}$`, in the definition of `\fillrow`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\newlength\letterheight
\setlength\letterheight{.5in}
\def\midpitch{.6}
\parskip 0.3in
\def\stacktype{L}\def\stackalignment{l}
%From morsburg at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12537/
%how-can-i-make-a-horizontal-dashed-line/12553#12553
\def\dashfill{\cleaders\hbox to .6em{-}\hfill}
\newcommand\dashline[1]{\abovebaseline[-2pt]{\hbox to #1{\dashfill\hfil}}}
\def\myhline{\rule{\textwidth}{.3pt}}
\newcommand\blankrow{%
  \setstackgap{L}{\the\letterheight}%
  \stackon[\midpitch\letterheight]{%
    \stackon{\myhline}{\myhline}}{\dashline{\textwidth}}%
}
\newcommand\fillrow[1]{%
  \stackinset{l}{}{b}{}%
  {\scalerel*{\rule{0pt}{.85\ht\strutbox}\smash{#1}}{\blankrow}}{\blankrow}}
\begin{document}
\fillrow{ABC abc}

\fillrow{GHIJ ghij}

\blankrow
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**SUPPLEMENT**

hashable asks two things...how to get text (rather than math) font as the lettering, and how to add the line demarking descenders.  I just cobbled it together as a variant from above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\newlength\letterheight
\setlength\letterheight{.5in}
\def\midpitch{.6}
\def\bottompitch{.3}
\parskip 0.4in
\def\stacktype{L}\def\stackalignment{l}
%From morsburg at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12537/
%how-can-i-make-a-horizontal-dashed-line/12553#12553
\def\dashfill{\cleaders\hbox to .6em{-}\hfill}
\newcommand\dashline[1]{\abovebaseline[-2pt]{\hbox to #1{\dashfill\hfil}}}
\def\myhline{\rule{\textwidth}{.3pt}}
\newcommand\blankrow{%
  \setstackgap{L}{\the\letterheight}%
  \stackon[\midpitch\letterheight]{%
    \stackon{\smash{\stackunder[\bottompitch\letterheight]{\myhline}%
      {\dashline{\textwidth}}}}{\myhline}}{\dashline{\textwidth}}%
}
\newcommand\fillrow[1]{%
  \stackinset{l}{}{b}{}%
  {\scalerel*{$\rule{0pt}{.85\ht\strutbox}\smash{#1}$}{\blankrow}}{\blankrow}}
\begin{document}
\fillrow{ABC abc}

\fillrow{GHIJ ghij}

\blankrow
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So the problem here is that I have to do the rows individually instead of just typing a paragraph.  Tobi's response is much more in the spirit of what I'm looking for.  Can this be done as a multi-row (read, unknown number of rows)?

Comment: @randomlogic78 I'll continue to think about it, but no easy way comes to mind on how to make it continuous.

Comment: Is it possible to get this to work with any random font? I tried \setdefaultfont and \setmathfont to a different font (one of the handwriting fonts from Google Fonts) but was unable to get the output to change fonts. In case of the former there was no change. In the case of the latter, I get Package fontspec Warning: Font "Cookie" does not contain requested Script "Math"

Comment: @hashable Yes.  The method shown above actually uses the math font.  To change that to the text font, one actually has to delimit the first argument of `\scalerel*` in `$` signs (yes, it's a stupid convention).  Therefore, alternately defining `\newcommand\fillrow[1]{\stackinset{l}{}{b}{}{\scalerel*{$\rule{0pt}{.85\ht\strutbox}\smash{#1}$}{\blankrow}}{\blankrow}}` will use the upright roman font of the document.  You will have to adjust the value of `\midpitch` to match the new font's ex proportion.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Thanks. I had missed your instruction in the answer to enclose between $ signs. Making that change and setting a roman font worked. Now I am trying to add another solid line at the bottom where the lowercase letters terminate similar to the solid line at the top where the Uppercase begins. Not quite able to figure that one out. Tobi's example has rows with 4 lines in each row. Trying to reproduce that with the stackon but no luck so far.

Comment: @hashable Please see my **SUPPLEMENT**