# Mathematical handwriting worksheets

Tags: math-mode

Similar to [Handwriting Drill Sheets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140514/handwriting-drill-sheets) question; however, I need it to work in math mode.

The problem is that my students don't seem to understand the location and spacing when writing their home work.  Mostly because their language has a radically different spacinig.

For example:

```
   $\log_2^{4^{2x}}$
```

Instead of

```
 $\log_2 4^{2x}$
```

I would like to have some worksheets of various equations so they can practice  the proper spacing and write neater, and to save my time grading their homework.

I have tried the examples listed, but the math mode spacing was way off. 
Also, none of the \setfont commands worked for me. all the fonts were not found.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

 % necessary packages
 \usepackage{tikz}

 % set the font
 \usepackage{fontspec}
 \setmainfont{Zapfino}% from http://www.fontsquirrel.com/

 % help length to store width of text
 \newlength{\lengthoftext}

   % increase baseline skip
 \usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{4}

 % define height of lowercase letters
\newcommand{\lowercaseheight}{1ex}
% define height of uppercase letters
\newcommand{\uppercaseheight}{2ex}
% define depth of descenders
\newcommand{\descenderdepth}{-2.2ex}
% you may add more values here and then us them in the {tikzpicture}
% to add more line to your grid


% package to have a "every line" hook
\usepackage{lineno}

\newenvironment{drillsheet}{%
% let the "line numbers" start directly at the text
\setlength\linenumbersep{0pt}%
% let the "line numbers" be the grid
\renewcommand{\thelinenumber}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
            % baseline
            \draw [ultra thick] ((0,0) -- ++(\textwidth,0);
            % lowercase height
            \draw ((0,\lowercaseheight) -- ++(\textwidth,0);
            % uppercase height
            \draw [thick] (0,\uppercaseheight) -- ++(\textwidth,0);
            % descender depth
            \draw (0,\descenderdepth) -- ++(\textwidth,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
% the font and color of the numbers must be set explicitly
\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\normalfont\color{black}}
% start "line numbering", i.e. the grid
\begin{linenumbers}%
    % set text color to gray
    \color{black!25}%
}{
% end "numbering", i.e. the grid
\end{linenumbers}%
}

\begin{document}
\Large
\begin{drillsheet}
 $\log_2 2^{2x}$ 
 $\int_{i+1}^{\infty} e^{2x}\,dx$

\end{drillsheet}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Jubobs I have done that, do you have an answer?

Comment: No, but you stand a better chance of getting one now that an MWE has been provided.

Comment: It may not be perfect, but writing `$\log{}_2 2^{2x}$` seems to help.